# Unzipping a file from Base64 to string using DotNetZip

Tags: c#, streamreader, memorystream

When I am trying to unzip a file in code I get the following error.

```
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean leaveOpen)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream)
   at Arkle.AzureServiceBusSample.MessageFetcher.ConvertBase64ZippedStringToNormalString(String stringBase64Zipped) in c:\CodeTfsArklePosBenLenovo\Arkle.AzureServiceBusSample\Arkle.AzureServiceBusSample\MessageFetcher.cs:line 171
   at Arkle.AzureServiceBusSample.MessageFetcher.DownloadMessages(String username, String password, String identifier) in c:\CodeTfsArklePosBenLenovo\Arkle.AzureServiceBusSample\Arkle.AzureServiceBusSample\MessageFetcher.cs:line 92
   at Arkle.AzureServiceBusSample.MessageFetcher.ReceiveMessages(String username, String password, String endPoint, String subscriptionName) in c:\CodeTfsArklePosBenLenovo\Arkle.AzureServiceBusSample\Arkle.AzureServiceBusSample\MessageFetcher.cs:line 48
```

System.ArgumentException: Stream was not readable.
at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, Boolean
detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, |nt32 bufferSize, Boolean |eaveOpen)
at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream)

It happens on the line `var streamReader1 = new StreamReader(ms);` I have checked and just above that I am able to save the file to disk and it is unzipped correctly. However I need to unzip it directly to a memory stream.

I'm using DotNetZip version 1.9.2.

My Code:

```
    using ionic.zip;

    .............
    public static string UnzipToString(string stringBase64Zipped)
    {
        var bytesZipFile = Convert.FromBase64String(stringBase64Zipped);

        var msZipFile = new MemoryStream(bytesZipFile);
        msZipFile.Position = 0;
        using (var zipFile1 = ZipFile.Read(msZipFile))
        {
            zipFile1.Save(string.Format(@"C:\Temp\{0}.zip", Guid.NewGuid()));  // This works
            var zipEntry1 = zipFile1.Entries.First();

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ms.Position = 0;
                zipEntry1.Extract(ms);
                var streamReader1 = new StreamReader(ms);
                var result = String.Empty;
                ms.Position = 0;
                result = streamReader1.ReadToEnd();

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Line and error when it stopz]

I have got a new error now when I try and set the memeorystream position to 0 as per the suggestion below.

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.

   at System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed()

   at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Position(Int64 value)

   at Arkle.AzureServiceBusSample.MessageFetcher.ConvertBase64ZippedStringToNormalString(String stringBase64Zipped) in c:\CodeTfsArklePosBenLenovo\Arkle.AzureServiceBusSample\Arkle.AzureServiceBusSample\MessageFetcher.cs:line 171

   at Arkle.AzureServiceBusSample.MessageFetcher.DownloadMessages(String username, String password, String identifier) in c:\CodeTfsArklePosBenLenovo\Arkle.AzureServiceBusSample\Arkle.AzureServiceBusSample\MessageFetcher.cs:line 92

   at Arkle.AzureServiceBusSample.MessageFetcher.ReceiveMessages(String username, String password, String endPoint, String subscriptionName) in c:\CodeTfsArklePosBenLenovo\Arkle.AzureServiceBusSample\Arkle.AzureServiceBusSample\MessageFetcher.cs:line 48
```

Comment: Change your error message to text not an image LAZY!

Comment: Really, you can even make a mistake, while using answers =D `ms.Position` can be only set **after** you populate it with something (in this case, after `Extract`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are going to archieve. Here is my sample code which works

```
        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"e:\scripts_04-10-2014.zip");
            var zipAsBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

            foreach (var item in GetUnzippedItemsAsStream(zipAsBase64))
            {
                using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(@"e:\", item.Item1), FileMode.CreateNew,
                        FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    item.Item2.CopyTo(fs);
                }
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Tuple<string, Stream>> GetUnzippedItemsAsStream(string stringBase64Zipped)
        {
            var bytesZipFile = Convert.FromBase64String(stringBase64Zipped);
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytesZipFile))
            {
                using (var zipFile = ZipFile.Read(ms))
                {
                    foreach (var zipEntry in zipFile.Entries)
                    {
                        var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
                            zipEntry.Extract(outputStream);
                            yield return new Tuple<string, Stream>(zipEntry.FileName, new MemoryStream(outputStream.ToArray()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Please note the following code

```
  zipEntry.Extract(outputStream);
  yield return new Tuple<string, Stream>(zipEntry.FileName, new MemoryStream(outputStream.ToArray()));
```

I was needed to create new MemoryStream with old.ToArray() ([which works even with closed MemoryStreams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) because there is a [known issue](https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd/issues/4) in current DotNetZipLib about closing the stream after extracting.

Answer (score 1):

```
zipEntry1.Extract(ms);
ms.Position = 0;
var streamReader1 = new StreamReader(ms);
```

Reset the MemoryStream position to be the start of the stream.